# d3.js basic query + Visualization suggestions

Tags: svg, html5-canvas, d3.js, data-visualization

I was going through the d3.js documentation , it says :

> D3 helps you bring data to life using HTML, SVG and CSS.

There are nice visualizations given in the example section but I wanted to clarify whether it uses SVG only or HTML 5 canvas too ?

I intend to do a highly interactive,large data driven, animation rich visualization and was considering d3.js.

Can someone please clarify or offer alternate suggestions which js visualization library I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/d3-js/KuAMZlJ-aVE

You'll find it easier to stick to SVG if you're using D3.

Here's an example using `canvas` http://bl.ocks.org/2409451